# the time complexity of an generateParenthesis algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Code:

```cpp
vector<string> generateParenthesis(int n) {
    vector<string> dp[n+1];
    dp[0] = {""};
    dp[1] = {"()"};
    for(int i=2; i<=n; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++) {
            for(string& a: dp[j])
            for(string& b: dp[i-1-j])
            {
                dp[i].push_back("("s + a + ")" + b);
            }
        }
    }
    return dp[n];
}
```

How to figrue out its time complexity?

I am confused about how to process the two inner loop

Comment: https://adrianmejia.com/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm-code-big-o-notation/#:~:text=Let's%20use%20T(n)%20as,statement%20or%20group%20of%20statements.&text=T(n)%20%3D%20t(,constant%20time%20O(1)%20.

I guess this will help you

Comment: @Aravind Thanks, but it seems not helpful because the code doesn't belong to any basic complexity type in the article. I have found a concept called Catalan number, which relate to my question.